Can a function be created in the global scope from a .ps1 script's script block?
Consider a PowerShell script named s.ps1 with content
1/0

and the hypothetical function
NAME
    New-GlobalFunction

SYNOPSIS
    Creates a new function in global scope from a script.

SYNTAX
    New-GlobalFunction [-ScriptPath] <string> [-FunctionName] <string>

I am hoping to be able to define global function Invoke-S using New-GlobalFunction such that Invoke-S produces error position information showing the correct file similar to the following:
PS C:\> New-GlobalFunction -ScriptPath .\s.p1 -FunctionName Invoke-S; Invoke-S
RuntimeException: C:\s.ps1:1
Line |
   1 |  1/0
     |  ~~~
     | Attempted to divide by zero.
----------

Attempted to divide by zero.
at <ScriptBlock>, C:\s.ps1: line 1

Note the mention of the original file c.ps1.
The architecture of PowerShell suggests this ought to be possible since scripts and functions are just script blocks:

In the PowerShell programming language, a script block is a collection of statements or expressions that can be used as a single unit. The collection of statements can be enclosed in braces ({}), defined as a function, or saved in a script file.

Indeed the script block defined by s.ps1 is accessible by Get-Command .\s.ps1 | % ScriptBlock.  The error with the correct location information above was produced by invoking that script block.  In fact, that script block can be turned into a local function with the command
New-Item -Path Function: -Name Invoke-S -Value (Get-Command .\s.ps1 | % ScriptBlock)

I have not, however, succeeded at creating such a global function.
Is there a way to define New-GlobalFunction such that an error produced by the script block defined in the file at -ScriptPath contains the correct file in its error position message?
Methods that don't work
The code below attempts the different methods I have tried for creating Invoke-S.  It outputs the following:
method                    new_error                 invoke_error                           stacktrace
------                    ---------                 ------------                           ----------
iex function global                                 Attempted to divide by zero.           at global:Invoke-S, <No file>…
function global: $sb      Missing function body in… The term 'Invoke-S' is not recognized… at <ScriptBlock>, C:\Users\Us…
New-Item Function:                                  The term 'Invoke-S' is not recognized… at <ScriptBlock>, C:\Users\Us…
New-Item global:Function: Cannot find drive. A dri… The term 'Invoke-S' is not recognized… at <ScriptBlock>, C:\Users\Us…
Get-Variable function:    Cannot find a variable w… The term 'Invoke-S' is not recognized… at <ScriptBlock>, C:\Users\Us…

These methods either do not create the function such that it is available in the caller's scope (error messages 'Invoke-S' is not recognized, or the stack trace does not mention the correct file (error message at global:Invoke-S, <No file>).
function New-GlobalFunction {
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)][string]   $ScriptPath  ,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)][string]   $FunctionName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)][ValidateSet(
        'iex function global'      ,
        'function global: $sb'     ,
        'New-Item Function:'       ,
        'New-Item global:Function:',
        'Get-Variable function:'    )]$Method
)
switch ($Method) {
    'iex function global' {
        Invoke-Expression `
            -Command "function global:$FunctionName {
                        $(Get-Content $ScriptPath)
                     }"
    }
    'function global: $sb' {
        $sb =
            Get-Command           `
                -Name $ScriptPath |
            % ScriptBlock
        # function global:Invoke-S $sb
        throw 'Missing function body in function declaration.'
    }
    'New-Item Function:' {
        New-Item                       `
            -ErrorAction Stop          `
            -Path        Function:     `
            -Name        $FunctionName `
            -Value (Get-Command $ScriptPath |
                    % ScriptBlock            )
    }
    'New-Item global:Function:' {
        New-Item                    `
            -ErrorAction Stop       `
            -Path  global:Function: `
            -Name  $FunctionName    `
            -Value (Get-Command $ScriptPath |
                    % ScriptBlock            )
    }
    'Get-Variable function:' {
        Get-Variable          `
            -Name 'function:' `
            -ErrorAction Stop
    }
}}

$(foreach ($method in 'iex function global'         ,
                      'function global: $sb',
                      'New-Item Function:'          ,
                      'New-Item global:Function:'   ,
                      'Get-Variable function:'       ) {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        method       = $method
        new_error    = $(try {$null =
                              New-GlobalFunction       `
                                -ScriptPath  .\s.ps1   `
                                -FunctionName Invoke-S `
                                -Method       $method   }
                        catch {$_})
        invoke_error = ($e =
                       try {Invoke-S -ErrorAction Stop}
                       catch {$_}     )
        stacktrace   = $e.ScriptStackTrace
        e            = $e
    }
    Remove-Item Function:Invoke-S -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}) |
    Format-Table `
        -Property @{e='method'      ;width=25},
                  @{e='new_error'   ;width=25},
                  @{e='invoke_error';width=38},
                  @{e='stacktrace'  ;width=30}

References

about_Functions
about_Scopes
about_Scripts



The following, using namespace variable notation, seems to work:
$FunctionName = 'Invoke-S'
$ScriptPath = '.\s.ps1'
Invoke-Expression @"
`${Function:global:$FunctionName} = (Get-Command "$ScriptPath").ScriptBlock
"@

The cmdlet-based equivalent of the above is actually simpler in this case, because the function name can directly be expressed in terms of a variable:
$FunctionName = 'Invoke-S'
$ScriptPath = '.\s.ps1'
Set-Content Function:global:$FunctionName (Get-Command $ScriptPath).ScriptBlock

In the context of your function:
function New-GlobalFunction {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)] [string] $ScriptPath,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)] [string] $FunctionName
  )
  Set-Content Function:global:$FunctionName (Get-Command $ScriptPath).ScriptBlock
}

# Sample call
New-GlobalFunction -ScriptPath .\s.ps1 -FunctionName Invoke-S


Explanation:
Specifically, the variable expression ${Function:global:Invoke-S} (the expanded form interpreted by Invoke-Expression[1]) / the (positionally implied) -Path argument with value Function:global:Invoke-S passed to Set-Content breaks down as follows:

Function: references the built-in Function: drive exposed by the Function provider

global:Invoke-S refers to a function named Invoke-S in the global scope; that is, global: is a scope modifier.

Such scope modifiers aren't often seen in function definitions, but they do work; e.g., function global:Test-Me { 'hi!' } defines a Test-Me function in the global scope.


The function name includes -, which is a character that requires enclosure of the entire (namespace-notation) variable-name expression in {...} in order to be recognized as a single variable expression.

Note how this is not necessary in argument-parsing mode in the Set-Content solution; Function:global:Invoke-S works fine as a single argument.



By assigning to ${Function:global:Invoke-S} / using that name as a path with Set-Content, the global Invoke-S function is either created or updated; what must be assigned / passed to the (positionally implied) -Value parameter of Set-Content is the function body (similarly, getting the value of this variable / using Get-Content Function:global:Invoke-S would return the function's body as a script block, assuming the function exists).

As an alternative to assigning / passing a script block, you can also assign / pass the body as a string (source-code text); however, in the case at hand only assigning a script block obtained via Get-Command preserves the full origin information, namely including the path of the originating .ps1 file.


Variant solution for defining a function in the caller's scope:

The solution above hinges on being able to use a scope modifier in the function name, namely global:

However, there is no way to specify a relative scope by way of a scope modifier, as would be needed if you wanted to define a function in the caller's scope - whatever scope the caller lives in.

Relative scopes, e.g. 1 to refer to the parent scope, are only supported via the -Scope parameter of entity-specific cmdlets, such as Set-Variable and Set-Alias; there is no Set-Function cmdlet.

Conceivably, however, even the generic provider cmdlets, such as New-Item and Set-Content, could be extended to provide entity-specific dynamic parameters (an existing example of such parameters are the -File and -Directory switches that are specific to the FileSystem provider).


This omission is the subject of GitHub discussion #16881 (reader discretion advised, due to inappropriate language), and the only - suboptimal - workaround for now is to use .NET reflection in order to access non-public members (whose continued existence [in that form] isn't guaranteed), notably the internal .GetScopeByID() method, as you note, which itself can only be accessed via an object obtained via another non-public API.

The solution below uses a simplified version of the code in the linked discussion, and, unlike the former, also supports putting the function, New-FunctionInCallerScope, inside a module, although the assumption is that it is only ever called from outside that module.




function New-FunctionInCallerScope {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)] [string] $ScriptPath,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)] [string] $FunctionName
  )

  # Binding flags for finding non-public instance members via reflection.
  $bindingFlags = [System.Reflection.BindingFlags] 'NonPublic, Instance'
  # Get the caller's internal session state, via $PSCmdlet.SessionState
  $sessionStateInternal = [System.Management.Automation.SessionState].
                            GetMethod('get_Internal', $bindingFlags).
                            Invoke($PSCmdlet.SessionState, $null)
  # Determine the scope index relative to $PSCmdlet.SessionState[Internal],
  # which is the *caller's* session state:
  # * If this function is inside a module, it lives in a different "session state"
  #   (scope domain), so use the caller's *current* scope (0) 
  #   (the caller is assumed to be an *outside* caller).
  # * If this function is a non-module function, it runs in the same "session state"
  #   as the caller, but in a *child* scope (unless dot-sourced), so use the parent
  #   scope (1).
  $callerScopeIndex = if ($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Module) { 0 } else { 1 }
  # Retrieve the target scope.
  $scope = $sessionStateInternal.GetType().
             GetMethod('GetScopeByID', $bindingFlags, [type[]] [int]).
             Invoke($sessionStateInternal, $callerScopeIndex)
  # Get the scope's function table. 
  $funcTable = $scope.GetType().
                 GetMethod('get_FunctionTable', $bindingFlags).
                 Invoke($scope, $null)
  # Create / update the function with the given name and script block from the given file.
  # Note: A [System.Management.Automation.FunctionInfo] instance must be assigned, which is
  #       is obtained via an aux. transitory, scope-local function whose name doesn't matter.
  $funcTable[$FunctionName] = New-Item Function:UnusedName -Value (Get-Command $ScriptPath).ScriptBlock
}

# Sample calls:

# Define function Invoke-S in the caller's scope.
New-FunctionInCallerScope -ScriptPath .\s.ps1 -FunctionName Invoke-S

# The function is now visible in this scope (and its descendants), 
# but not in any parent scope.
Invoke-S


[1] Note that while use of Invoke-Expression (iex) is safe in this particular case, it should generally be avoided.

I think you've covered everything from my OP.  I have been distracted by whether a numeric scope modifier can be used instead of global via a public API.  .GetScopeByID() indeed accepts numeric scopes, but it is internal.  I succeeded with reflection after coming across this befuddling discussion.  That OP has a representative demo.

Interesting, @alx9r. I've updated the answer with a solution that defines the function in the caller's scope, whatever scope that is, based on a streamlined version of the code in the GitHub discussion. Please see the new bottom section.

Conceivably...the generic provider cmdlets, such as New-Item and Set-Content, could be extended to provide entity-specific dynamic parameters...  I had this same thought.  That would be the idiomatic way to achieve the functionality, I think.

I think that the case where New-FunctionInCallerScope is in a module and is called from within that module isn't correctly handled. ($callerScopeIndex becomes 0 where it should be 1).  Otherwise this all looks pretty great to me.

Thanks, @alx9r - good point re calling from inside the same module, but supporting that use case too wasn't a design goal; I've updated the answer to make that clear.

@alx9r: I've also realized that what I said about Santiago's answer (it working to define a function in the caller's scope if placed inside a module with global: removed) isn't actually true, so I've removed it from the answer. It's unclear to me why, but I'm not inspired to go down that rabbit hole.

An alternative storing the CommandInfo in the value script block.
function New-GlobalFunction {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $ScriptPath,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $FunctionName,

        [Parameter()]
        [switch] $Force
    )

    $command = Get-Command $ScriptPath -ErrorAction Stop
    $null = $PSCmdlet.SessionState.InvokeProvider.Item.New(
        'function:',
        "global:$FunctionName",
        'Function',
        $command.ScriptBlock,
        $Force.IsPresent)
}


Thank you @SantiagoSquarzon.  Is there a particular reason you chose { & $command }.GetNewClosure() rather than ($command.ScriptBlock)?

@alx9r good point, didnt thought you'd see the original file in the stacktrace using .ScriptBlock but seems like it does
